# WordPress site loads badly on HTTPS.

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https

I have a WordPress site and it opens badly on HTTPS.

I want it to redirect to HTTP if anyone opens using HTTPS.

Tried putting the bellow code in .htaccess file -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]????
```

But it breaks the site to give error 500 on multiple sections.

My current .htaccess file is -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Please help, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say it 'opens badly', what do you mean? If you have a TLS cert and don't want HTTPS, get rid of the cert

Comment: It opens but does not load anything. I want to redirect https links to http, 300 redirection.

Comment: Btw, I am using cloudflare. Have not installed any TLS Cert.

Answer (score 1):

With Cloudflare, use (before others rules):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"'
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or you also can add Clouflare page rule (Cloudflare web site)